# SQLite : Begin-commit for WAL mode

Tags: database, sqlite

On reading [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), I learnt that in WAL mode , we have a concept of checkpointing.

Does that mean that I don't need to execute any `begin` (or is there any alternative) for WAL and simply need to execute `sqlite3_wal_checkpoint_v2` when I want to commit?

Answer (score 1):

In WAL mode, transactions work like in any other mode, and must be used like in any other mode.

What is different in WAL mode is that the changes made by committed transactions are written to the `-wal` file instead of to the actual database file.
A checkpoint just reorganizes the data, i.e., moves the changed data back into the database file.

Comment: Thanks. What my doubt was that why those `wal` and `shm` files are still kept there and are not removed when we checkpoint similar to `-jouranl` file which is removed when we commit